# How to share a X server between different users on the same machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg

On the same computer, accessible by ssh, i would like to start a X server with one user that could be used by all other users, currently when i do this, if i start an application with another user on the right display i ge the following error :

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyfreeglut (./visu.out): failed to open display ':0.0'
```

Is there a way of achieving this result ?

Comment: Take a look: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/197

Comment: @duDE I already tried to but xinit only fails (no program named "xterm" in PATH) and i didn't exactly understand what these answers were trying to achieve...